# Select columns according to previous row values

Tags: sql

I have a table called Members. In this table Members enroll, terminate and may enroll again
I need the earliest enroll date and the most recent Termdate if there's one otherwise null.

In the example, Member 1 should get 2018-01-01 for EnrolDate and null for Termdate.

```
Member_Id   EnrollDate      TermDate
=========   =========      =======
1           2018-01-01     null
1           2018-01-01     2018-06-30
1           2018-08-01     null
1           2018-08-01     2018-12-31
1           2019-01-01     null
2           …              …
2           …              …
```

For Member_Id  1, I should be selecting 2018-01-01 FOR EnrollDate and null for TermDate since 
the TermDate on the last line for this member is null.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like conditional aggregation, using `row_number()` to identify the most recent row::

```
select member_id, min(enrolldate),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then termdate end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by member_id order by enrolldate desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by member_id;
```

If `termdate` is increasing as `enrolldate` increases, then it is possible to use simple aggregation and a `case`:

```
select member_id, min(enrolldate),
       (case when max(enrolldate) = max(case when termdate is not null then enrolldate end)
             then max(termdate)
        end)
from t
group by member_id;
```

Basically, this checks if the maximum value of `enrolldate` for a non-NULL `termdate` is the maximum value for `enrolldate`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.